# Any Logic 6: event triggered sourced using conditions

Tags: events, anylogic

I am building a model simulating an order process tiggering a production flow. The production flow should be initiated once the order is placed. My idea is to use an event named "start production" that is monitoring a boolean, which is changed by the above order entity.

I am facing various issues:

1. When starting the simulation my startProduction variable is changing from its initial value false to true already applying the starting condition in the event
2. If I apply in the action of the event the command event.restart() the simulation crashes as anylogic is constantly re-checking the event condition

How can I either solve the above problems or simulate the start of production based on an order income with a conditional logic?

Comment: first why are you using anylogic 6? update yourself.

Second: why don't you just use the inject function when the order is placed instead of using the event?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking to complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment was the answer, let me add the answer here too.

It is always possible to use an event to trigger actions in your model, but it's also the most ineffective way, because you constantly running code that you may not need, making your simulation slower. The best thing you can do, whenever possible is to trigger things in the actions of your blocks. In this case when the order is generated you can use the inject function to add an agent to your production flow.

On the other hand, you can only use the restart function if the mode of your event is "user control" and it's probably the reason why you were getting an error.